# Finding $S$ such that $SAS^{-1} = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> > A is a square matrix of order $n$. $A$ is not a scalar matrix, i.e. $A \neq cI$ for any $c$. Prove the existence of an invertible matrix $S$, such that $SAS^{-1} = B$ with $B$'s first row's first entry = $0$.

How do I get started with this? I really don't know what $B$ looks like, so I'll probably have to use row and column operations on $A$ to get to the required $B$, however, I'm unable to see how. Please help.

Comment: See [Lemma 2 here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ be any non-zero vector that is not an eigenvector of $A$. Then the set $\{v,Av\}$ can be extended to a basis $\mathcal B = \{v,Av,v_3,\dots,v_n\}$ of $\Bbb F^n$.  We find that the matrix of $A$ relative to $\mathcal B$ has $(0,1,0,\dots,0)^T$ as its first column.

Thus, it suffices to select the change-of-basis matrix $S$ satisfying $S[x]_{\mathcal B} = x$.  That is, it suffices to take $S$ to be the matrix whose columns are $v,Av,v_3,\dots,v_n$.

---

*Alternative proof:*

**Claim:** There exist vectors $v,w$ with $w^Tv \neq 0$ and $w^TSv = 0$.

**Proof of Claim:** Select a non-zero vector $v$ which is *not* an eigenvector of $S$. It follows that $\ker v^T \neq \ker(Sv)^T$, but both kernels are $(n-1)$-dimensional subspaces. Now (noting that $x^Ty = y^Tx$), it suffices to select any element $w \in \ker(Sv)^T \setminus \ker v^T$.

If we are working over $\Bbb R$, the proof can be reframed as follows: once $v$ is chosen, it suffices to select a vector $w$ that is orthogonal to $Sv$ but not to $v$. $\quad \square$

Now, form an invertible matrix  $M = [v, b_2, \dots, b_n]$  in which $\{b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ constitutes a basis for $\ker w^T$, so that $w^Tb_j = 0$ for $j = 2,\dots,n$.  The first row in the inverse  $M^{-1}$ must be $k\,w^T$ for some scalar $k$.  If we take $S = M^{-1}$, we find that the first diagonal element of $SAS^{-1}$ is $(kw)^TSv = 0$, as desired.

(Proof adapted from [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf))

Comment: How does it follow that that $\ker w^T \neq \ker(Sw)^T$?

Comment: For (column) vectors $x,y$, $\ker x^T \subseteq \ker y^T$ can only happen if $x$ and $y$ and multiples. If $w$ is not an eigenvector, then $w,Sw$ are not multiples.

Comment: Why $\subseteq$ and not $=$?

Comment: If $y = 0$ it's $\subseteq$

Comment: Okay, great! Please help me out here. I'm able to show that if the two row vectors are multiples of each other, then they share the same nullspace, but unable to prove that if they have the same nullspace, they must necessarily be multiples. How do I go about this? I started with assuming a basis for $\ker x^T = \ker y^T$. Also, I don't see why this is exactly $(n-1)$ dimensional. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To the latter point, they're $(n-1)$ dimensional by the rank-nullity theorem

Comment: Intuitively, it comes down to the fact that if $x$ is not parallel to $y$, then there exists a vector perpendicular to $x$ but not perpendicular to $y$.  If you want a rigorous proof, then 
$$
\ker(x^T) \cap \ker(y^T) = \ker \pmatrix{x^T\\y^T}.
$$
If $x,y$ are not multiples then the matrix has full rank and the kernel must be $(n-2)$-dimensional by the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103207/discussion-between-arya-stark-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: Just to confirm, how did you find the first diagonal entry of $SAS^{-1}$? Is there a smart way? Also, in the alternative proof, where did we use the fact that $A$ is not a scalar matrix?

Comment: Note that the columns of $AS^{-1}$ are $Av,Ab_2,\dots,Ab_n$. We can compute the entries of $S(AS^{-1})$ by taking dot-products of the rows of $S$ with the columns of $AS^{-1}$.

Comment: On another note, I just noticed that I have a mistake. I'll have to change up the claim a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has a non-zero entry in the first row, say, $a_{1i}\neq0$, take $S = I_{n}+ \frac{a_{11}e_{i}e^T_{1}}{a_{1i}}$

Else, if $A$ has a non-zero entry in the first column, say, $a_{j1}\neq0$, take $S = I_{n}- \frac{a_{11}e_{1}e^T_{j}}{a_{j1}}$